# Test default values and expressions of Mojos using Maven Plugin Testing Harness:

Tags: unit-testing, maven

I have a problem using the Maven Plugin Testing Harness (2.0-alpha1): When I want to test my Mojo, the default values and expressions for parameters are not applicable.
I have the following parameter:

```
/**
 * <p>The output file to write the settings to.</p>
 *
 * @parameter default-value="${project.build.directory}/myProperties.properties" expression="${properties.file}"
 */

private String file;
```

When I run my unit tests this property is always null. I tried to inject a MavenProjectStub which returns `${project.build.directory}` successfully but this is not applied to my Mojo parameter.

Is there any way to enable default values and expressions like `${project.build.directory}` inside my Mojos during the tests?

Answer (score 10):

So it looks like [they added `lookupConfiguredMojo` for just this use case](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPLUGINTESTING-23). It took me a while to figure out how to call that because you need a properly configured `MavenProject` to use it. Here's what worked for me:

```
File pomFile = ...

MavenExecutionRequest executionRequest = new DefaultMavenExecutionRequest();
ProjectBuildingRequest buildingRequest = executionRequest.getProjectBuildingRequest();
ProjectBuilder projectBuilder = this.lookup(ProjectBuilder.class);
MavenProject project = projectBuilder.build(pomFile, buildingRequest).getProject();

MyMojo mojo = (MyMojo) this.lookupConfiguredMojo(project, "my-goal");
...
```

Comment: This may be a maven versioning issue (I'm working with maven 3.1.1), but on running this code, I get an `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid repository system session: the session may not be null`. Were there any other configurations that you had to set up to get this to work?

Comment: Sorry I never saw this comment until now, but the code that did this was here: https://code.google.com/p/cleartk/source/browse/jcasgen-maven-plugin/src/test/java/org/cleartk/plugin/JCasGenMojoTest.java?r=183f61f1decb199fec571c2eb49de7abd4053f4a

Comment: using maven 3.6.0 and dependencies 3.1.0 above code sequence works.

Answer (score 8):

I hit a bunch of issues including this when testing my plugin. Each problem only took a few lines to fix but finding them wasn't easy. The pointers here helped!

I've combined them in a 
[BetterAbstractMojoTestCase.java](https://github.com/ahgittin/license-audit-maven-plugin/blob/1a9795a14eef2d4d48a08cae6ef4bfbd974ef98d/src/test/java/org/heneveld/maven/license_audit/BetterAbstractMojoTestCase.java) class. It contains the magic lines which solved the half-dozed issues I hit; and it gives a `lookupConfiguredMojo(File pom, String goal)` method for your issue here.

Comment: Using Steve's code for the unit test but replacing `executionRequest.getProjectBuildingRequest()` with a call to your code via `newMavenSession().getProjectBuildingRequest()` has got me past this roadblock. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Actually got a few steps further and discovered I needed the `MavenProject` which the test wasn't creating in the Plexus container, so I had to set it manually into the Mojo using the project instantiated in Steve's snippet.

Comment: Tried it now -- still have an issue with:
    @Parameter(
        defaultValue = "${project.build.directory}/jgiven-reports/qa-html")
    protected File    outputDirectory;

the `defaultValue` is resolved as `C:\projects\qa-automation\qa-jgiven-reporter-maven-plugin\target\test-classes\target\test-classes\jgiven-reports\qa-html` -- `target\test-classes\` appears twice -- any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this very same problem and couldn't find any solution, so I decided to fix it myself. I've checked out the source code for the latest version of the maven-plugin-testing-harness (which is 2.0-alpha-1 at the moment) and placed it in my own github repository.

You will have to checkout the code from there and build it locally.

The only change you need to make in your project is replace the dependency in your POM. I used my own domain/groupId name instead of the Apache one just to avoid any conflicts (and confusion) with future Apache releases.

This is what you need to put in your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.menttis.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And this is the repository where you can grab the code from: https://github.com/grighetto/maven-plugin-testing-harness

Comment: Gianluca, I'd very much like to know more about what you changed in order to support the expressions from MavenProjectStub, as I'm running into the same situation. I'd rather understand what modified code I'm using before I just grab the whole project and start relying on it... care to elaborate on what changes you needed to make? I scanned through some of the classes but couldn't tell where your changes were.

Comment: @Meghan, you can take a look at this specific commit on GitHub: https://github.com/grighetto/maven-plugin-testing-harness/commit/c711fb0c8e9b03fe886a5db5b888478f1b4dc70a
You may have figured this out by now, but the relevant changes have been applied to the AbstractMojoTestCase class (check the lines from 295 through 311). The problem, before this fix, was that the plugin wasn't extracting the parameters from the Mojo, which should then be passed on to a PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.I hope this clarifies a bit.

Answer (score 0):

For version 3+:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

spent a while confused about this myself before realising I was mixing the annotation syntax with the javadoc syntax.

```
@Parameter(property = "project.build.directory")
private String projectBuildDir;
```

Then concatenate your file name with that value to complete the path in your code.