# Testing Maven Plugin with JUnit and Working with a Test-POM

Tags: java, maven

I'm developing a custom Maven plugin. For testing, I use JUnit tests with the `MojoRule`. The testing itself works fine (I can read the plugin configuration defined in the test pom). However, I want to test access to the project's artifacts.

So far, I haven't figured out how to tell my test class:

- to treat a separate directory as a source folder for my test project
- to execute `package` before my plugin
- to get the `MavenProject` as a field in my class (it's null at runtime)

My Mojo class looks like this:

```
/**
 * Identifies potential actions from the project's source code.
 *
 * @goal identify
 */
public class IdentifyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

  @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}")
  private MavenProject project;

  @Override
  public void execute() {
    getLog().info("Project: " + project);
    for (Artifact nextArtifact : project.getArtifacts()) {
      getLog().info("Next artifact: " + nextArtifact);
    }
  }

}
```

The test class looks like this:

```
public class IdentifyMojoTest {

  private static final String TEST_POM_FILE_PATH = "src/test/resources";
  private static final String TEST_POM_FILE_NAME = "test-pom.xml";

  private MojoRule rule = new MojoRule();

  @Ignore("Requires mvn install")
  @Test
  public void execute_loadWithPlexus_noExceptions() throws Exception {
    // Arrange
    String goalName = "identify";
    File testPom = getTestPom();

    // Act
    IdentifyMojo identifyMojo = (IdentifyMojo) rule.lookupMojo(goalName, testPom);
    identifyMojo.execute();

    // Assert

  }

  @Rule
  public MojoRule getRule() {
    return rule;
  }

  @NotNull
  @Contract(" -> new")
  private File getTestPom() {
    return new File(TEST_POM_FILE_PATH, TEST_POM_FILE_NAME);
  }

}
```

The test POM looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.example.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the test running by adding this element to the plugin's `<configuration>` block:

```
<project implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.stubs.MavenProjectStub"/>
```

This made the Mojo print `Project: MavenProject: null:null:null @ ".

Apparently, the testing harness doesn't provide any default values at all, so I have to inject an instance of `MavenProject` in the configuration myself. However, this solves my other problems too, since I don't have to run the `package` goal and just have my `MavenProjectStub` return some artifacts I built in code.

Source: [Unit Testing Maven Mojo - Components and parameters are null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512404/unit-testing-maven-mojo-components-and-parameters-are-null)